# Qt4 how to capture focus event on QLineEdit widget or others

Tags: events, qt4

how can I capture focus event in some widget (for example QLineEdit) without
creating a new widget ?

Thans for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create a SLOT - focusChanged(QWidget*,QWidget*)
in your MainWindow class and connect SIGNAL focusChanged(QWidget*,QWidget*) from QApplication in your main function.

in main.cpp:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(focusChanged(QWidget*,QWidget*)), &w, SLOT(focusChanged(QWidget*,QWidget*)));
```

in mainwindow.h

add slot

```
public slots:
    void focusChanged(QWidget* old, QWidget* now);
```

in mainwindow.cpp

add implementation

```
void MainWindow::focusChanged(QWidget* old, QWidget* now)
{
}
```